# Scrapy через множество ссылок для получения текста

Tags: html, python, https, scrapy

**Суть:**

Необходимо чтобы `scrapy` проходил по множеству ссылок, если он парсит `Bad request` с `html` - ссылка пропускается и к `id` страницы добавляется `1` и так до определенного номера.

**Псевдокод:**

```
class exampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"  
    allowed_domains = ["examle.com/c/test"]
    start_urls = ["examle.com/c/test/1/p"]
    max_page_index = 200000

    def parse(self, response):
             ...
             если:
                 извлеченный текст из <title></title>
                 содержит Bad Request
                 index += 1 (то есть ссылка будет в виде examle.com/c/test/2/p)
             или:
                 print(текущая ссылка валидна)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class TestSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test_Spider'
    allowed_domains = ["127.0.0.1"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://127.0.0.1:81/504.php"]
    ERRORS_MAX = 20

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_item)


    def parse_item(self, response):
        value = response.xpath("//a/text()").extract()[0].split(":")[0]
        eto_nenado = "12"

        if eto_nenado in value:
            some_page_index = "thisisindexfromresponseurl"
            errors = self.crawler.stats.get_value("ERRORS_%s" % some_page_index, 0)
            if errors < self.ERRORS_MAX:
                self.crawler.stats.set_value("ERRORS_%s" % some_page_index, errors+1)
                yield scrapy.Request(response.url, dont_filter = True, callback = self.parse_item)

        # do someting
        # yield item
```